# Binding and updating values from select option to table row cells in NiceGUI

Tags: python, nicegui

I have multiple different tabs that all collect data based on multiple different dropdowns and inputs in a class specific to each tab. As a verification of this process, I decided to output the state dictionary of the specific class of the tab in the table. But when I change the input of the dropdown or input section, it does not update the table.

Here is the following code for the `app.py`:

```
# def program header table ui
@ui.refreshable
def ph_table_refreshable(columns, rows):
    ui.table(columns=columns, rows = rows, row_key = 'attribute')

# tab settings
with ui.tabs() as tabs:
    ui.tab('Program Header')

programheader= ProgramHeader()
with ui.tab_panels(tabs):
    with ui.tab_panel('Program Header'):
        with ui.row().classes('w-full'):
            with ui.column():
                programheader.op_id = ui.number(label="Operation ID", min=0, value = 0).value
                programheader.machine_name = ui.select(label="Machine Name", options=machines).value
                programheader.print_reference = ui.input(label="Print Reference").value
                programheader.num_operations = ui.number(label="Number of Operations", value=2).value
            with ui.column():
                ui.label("Program Header Properties")
                ph_columns, ph_rows = programheader.get_table_data
                ph_table_refreshable(ph_columns, ph_rows)
                ui.button("Update", on_click=ph_table_refreshable.refresh())

ui.run()
```

and here it is for the program header class being imported from another script called `sequences.py`:

```
class ProgramHeader:
    def __init__(
        self, 
        op_id: int = 0, 
        machine_name: str = '', 
        print_reference: str = '', 
        num_operations: int = 2, 
        operation_notes: str = None, 
        choice: str = 'active', 
        up_to_date: str = None
    ):
        # input variables
        self.op_id = op_id
        self.machine_name = machine_name
        self.print_reference = print_reference
        self.num_operations = num_operations
        
        # not input variables
        self.operation_notes = "" if not operation_notes else f" - {operation_notes}"
        self.choice = choice.upper()
        self.up_to_date = up_to_date
        self.date = datetime.now().date()
        self.total_date = f"{self.date} AND UP" if not self.up_to_date else f"{self.date} UP THROUGH {self.up_to_date}"

    @property
    def get_table_data(self):
        columns = [
            {'name': 'attribute', 'label': 'Attribute', 'field': 'attribute', 'required': True, 'align': 'left'},
            {'name': 'value', 'label': 'Value', 'field': 'value'}
        ]

        rows = [{'attribute': k, 'value': v} for k, v in self.__dict__.items()]
        return columns, rows
```

I have tried following the bindable properties on the documentation website but I have not been able to understand how to use them. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without checking every detail of your code, the button's click handler seems wrong:

```py
ui.button("Update", on_click=ph_table_refreshable.refresh())
```

should be

```py
ui.button("Update", on_click=ph_table_refreshable.refresh)
```

Otherwise you call `refresh` once when instantiating the button, but because the `refresh` function returns `None`, the `on_click` handler is set to `None`.

---

#### Update

The other thing causing trouble is that you read the value of the input element right when constructing them. At this time the value is `None`. Later you never read these values again, so the table doesn't change.

I moved this part into `ph_table_refreshable()`, which should access the `programheader` and the input elements itself to get the most recent values whenever it is refreshed:

```py
class ProgramHeader:

    def __init__(self, op_id: int = 0, machine_name: str = '', print_reference: str = '', num_operations: int = 2,
                 operation_notes: str = None, choice: str = 'active', up_to_date: str = None):
        self.op_id = op_id
        self.machine_name = machine_name
        self.print_reference = print_reference
        self.num_operations = num_operations
        self.operation_notes = "" if not operation_notes else f" - {operation_notes}"
        self.choice = choice.upper()
        self.up_to_date = up_to_date
        self.date = datetime.now().date()
        self.total_date = f"{self.date} AND UP" if not self.up_to_date else f"{self.date} UP THROUGH {self.up_to_date}"

    @property
    def table_data(self):
        columns = [{'name': 'attribute', 'label': 'Attribute', 'field': 'attribute', 'required': True, 'align': 'left'},
                   {'name': 'value', 'label': 'Value', 'field': 'value'}]
        rows = [{'attribute': k, 'value': v} for k, v in self.__dict__.items()]
        return columns, rows

@ui.refreshable
def ph_table_refreshable():
    programheader.op_id = op_id.value
    programheader.machine_name = machine_name.value
    programheader.print_reference = print_reference.value
    programheader.num_operations = num_operations.value
    columns, rows = programheader.table_data
    ui.table(columns=columns, rows=rows, row_key='attribute')

programheader = ProgramHeader()
with ui.row().classes('w-full'):
    with ui.column():
        op_id = ui.number(label="Operation ID", min=0, value=0)
        machine_name = ui.select(label="Machine Name", options=['A', 'B'])
        print_reference = ui.input(label="Print Reference")
        num_operations = ui.number(label="Number of Operations", value=2)
    with ui.column():
        ui.label("Program Header Properties")
        ph_table_refreshable()
        ui.button("Update", on_click=ph_table_refreshable.refresh)
```

Comment: Hi! I have tried this but it is still not updating.